# Javascript error "MyIdentifier is not defined"

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I broke the google map [on this page](http://www.comehike.com/hikes/search_hikes.php?all=yes&when=f&redirect=yes), and it is giving me an error:

> placeHikesMarkers is not defined

What is the best way to debug JS in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/errors) or [Chrome Console](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html). You have this in Firebug:

```
syntax error
http://www.comehike.com/hikes/search_hikes.php?all=yes&when=f&redirect=yes
Line 577

var lng = ;
```

And:

```
placeHikesMarkers is not defined
http://www.comehike.com/hikes/search_hikes.php?all=yes&when=f&redirect=yes
Line 1
```

This particular issue is because your script stops at the first, then calls the second, which is not defined because the error was inside the function:

```
var placeHikesMarkers = function(){

    var lat = -122;
    var lng = ;
```

Comment: ... And I quickly found and diagnosed the issue (and would have had it fixed) in minutes, all without knowing anything about the html, css or javascript. Get it, learn to use it, you'll love it. :)